# ColdFusion: Variable CHRIS3 is undefined. But the page still works, except with the initial error message

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to find the root cause of the error message when viewing my CF page, however the page still functions correctly.  I have to apologize now. This is my third day using CF.  I really appreciate any help

```
 <cfsetting showDebugOutput="Yes">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

  <label for="Chris3">Please Select.<br />
  </label>
  <select name="Chris3" id="Chris3">
    <option value="COOKWARE/CUTLERY">COOKWARE/CUTLERY</option>
    <option value="BAKEWARE/ ELECTRICS">BAKEWARE/ ELECTRICS</option>
    <option selected="selected">Please Select one</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" id="SUBMIT" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p>
<cfset Chris3 ="Form.Chris3">
  <cffile action="append"
  file="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PURGE\WS\DEPTM.txt"
  output="#Chris3#">
```

Error Message:

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.

Error Occurred While Processing Request
Variable CHRIS3 is undefined.

```
The error occurred in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PURGE\WS\PURGE.cfm: line 29

27 :   <cffile action="append"
28 :   file="C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\PURGE\WS\DEPTM.txt"
29 :   output="#Chris3#">
30 : </p>
31 : <p>Below are Departments that have finished reviewing the purge</p>


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Resources: 
Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax. 
Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem. 


Browser   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) 
Remote Address   192.168.97.38 
Referrer    
Date/Time   06-Apr-12 03:30 PM 

Stack Trace (click to expand)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are two issues:

The first issue is where you're setting the variable `Chris3`. If you want it to be equal to the value passed into the form, then you need to use

```
    <cfset Chris3 = form.Chris3 />
```

.. the way you have it written now it's storing the literal string "form.Chris3" as the entered value.

The second is that field does not exist until after the form is submitted. You can do one of two things to handle this. Either add a `cfparam`, like Scott suggested, so the value is always defined:

```
  <cfparam name="form.Chris3" default="" />
```

OR you can add a check to see if the form has been submitted before you access set the value to your variable:

```
 <cfif StructKeyExists(form,'Chris3')>
```

If you used `<cfparam>` simply check the field's length instead:

```
 <cfif Len(Trim(form.Chris3))>
```

As far as the value showing up undefined, I don't see anything wrong with your code. I copy and pasted it and it worked fine on my machine.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The page was a successes.
p.s.  I just received a award for this. Double thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set (or param) the value form.chris3 at the top of the page, this error is expected the first time you run that page, since the form scope is likely empty. Once the form is submitted, it will work as expected.

Not sure what you are trying to do, but wrapping the CFFILE in a CFIF that checks for the existence of 'form.chris3' before doing the CFFILE (or setting the value of 'form.chris3' to 'chris3').